# Port R expression to MATLAB

Tags: r, matlab

If I have an NxP matrix G and and PX1 vector Lambda I can do this in R

```
G = matrix(c(1/2,1/4,3/4,5/2),nrow=2,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
Lambda = c(1,2)
M = t(G)%*%(c((1/(1+G%*%Lambda)^(2)))*G)
M
            [,1]        [,2]
[1,] -0.07484568 -0.07240226
[2,] -0.07240226 -0.15279921
```

And I get a PxP matrix, which is what I want. But in Matlab, this is the best I could figure out is doing something like

```
b=1./((1+G*Lambda).^2)
transpose(G(i,:))*G(i,:)*b(i)
```

and looping over this idea. But, I want to do a simulation study and would prefer a vectorized way of doing this. If someone could help me figure this out I would be very happy.

Comment: Please show some reproducible example.

Comment: Can you post some example input and output data to go with your R expression? And an explanation of what your code does.

Comment: @akrun Since the dimensions of the matrices are given, I think the question is clear. It is not dependent on the particular values.

Comment: @Arpi but because it crosses two languages, by posting what the code is trying to do instead of just plain R code the OP might get more solutions from MATLAB experts who don't read R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that Matlab cannot reuse vector elements if dimensions mismatch, thus the solution is little bit more complicated.

```
n = 2;
p = 4;

G = reshape(1:(n*p), [n, p]);
Lambda = (1:p).';

A = (1./(1+G*Lambda).^(2));
% since Matlab cannot reuse the vector elements if dimensions mismatch as R
B = reshape(repmat(A,p,1).*G(:), size(G));
G.'*B
```

You can make a one-liner from the above code as well.
I still find the way how Matlab handles operations more intuitive, in line with mathematics.

**EDIT:** based on @Dan's suggestions:

better solution to obtain `B`:

```
B = bsxfun(@times, A, G);
```

Comment: I'm not 100% what you're trying to do here but your "reusing vector elements if dimensions mismatch" is often called broadcasting and in MATLAB it's generally better to use `bsxfun` than `repmat`: `B = bsxfun(@times, A, G);`. You might need to transpose `A` there, I didn't check the dimensions.

Comment: @Dan Thanks for the information regarding broadcasting. You are right, it is more efficient with `bsxfun`. Updated the answer with your suggestion.

Comment: This is a very clever solution. Thank you Arpi!